# Package name contains unexpecting level com.tmp

Tags: android-studio, package

My Android Studio application called `calendar` contains package `spectorsky`, and it works. However, when I try to save the settings by

```
SharedPreferences calendarSettings;
calendarSettings = getSharedPreferences("calendarINI", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
calendarSettings.edit().putLong("TimeZone",Double.doubleToLongBits(Riseset.timezone));
```

and then seek saved xml via Device File Explorer, I see my package on the strange level `com.tmp.spectorsky.calendar', see printscreen:
[image]

My file system on the hard disk does not contain `tmp` directory anywhere concerning this application. I see that the package names on other examples contain `com` level (somewhat like `com.package.app`), but no `tmp` domain is observed.
So, the question: why `tmp` level appears in my package name, and can (and should) I get rid it?

Answer (score 0):

Level `com.tmp` was written it two places: in the manifest file `AndroidManifest.xml` and in the gradle (right-click on the app in project view, Open Module Settings, ApplicationID). Then, after cleaning the project, wrong `com.tmp....` directory can be deleted from the Device File Explorer.